# CSS double borders with second border going all the way to the top of the element

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to recreate this in css:

[image]

As you can see, it could be done easily like this:

```
border-top: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
border-left: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #848484;
border-right: 1px solid #848484;
```

And then we add:

```
box-shadow: 0.7px 0.7px 0 0.7px hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
```

But! This produces this:

[image]

Which has a 2pxborder at the bottom and right, rather than a 1px, due to the nature of box-shadow effectively adding the top and left 1 pixel on to the other sides. Outline won't do, since that goes all the way around. Is there any way I can crop this by 1px at the right and bottom?

Comment: Looks like a px is missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a JSBin Demo: http://jsbin.com/reqev/1/edit?html,css,output

Despite your title, I used a box-shadow to accomplish the effect you were going for.  Since you had already tried box-shadow, I assumed that you weren't completely against it, and just didn't have luck with your own implementation.  I apologize if my assumption was not correct.

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
  background: white;
}
button {
  border-right:  1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top:    none;
  border-left:   none;
  background:    #ddd;
  box-shadow:    inset 1px 1px #e2e2e2,
                 inset -1px -1px #848484;
  padding:       5px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, of course! So clever, using the inner shadow effect and putting the border on the external, perfect, thank you!!! EDIT: I've changed the topic title to reflect the fact it's not a problem using box-shadow ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two elements instead of one:

```
<div id="x"><div id="z">Button</div></div>
```

CSS

```
#x {
    border-top: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    border-left: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#z {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #838383;
    border-right: 1px solid #838383;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/28z9mo8w/3/

Comment: Could this be further simplified by using the ::after pseudo element?

Comment: Is there anything different? By the way, I change your code.http://jsfiddle.net/28z9mo8w/5/

Comment: @ToddMark that is missing the bottom lighter color of the original button's inner bevel

Comment: @StevenEllenStarar I don't think so since both `before` and `after` create elements with given content instead of the inner content of the parent. It's possible it could work with fixed button width.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is doable by still using box-shadow but setting an inset to it

So the E2E2E2 becomes a topand left border, the 00000 becomes a right and bottom border and the 848484 becomes an inset box shadow on 225 degrees

See this code for example

https://github.com/necolas/css3-facebook-buttons